# Apollo server 2.0 with Dynamodb schema validation

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, apollo-server

I am a newbie in Apollo server, graphql and Dynamodb. Can anyone here help me with Apollo Server 2.0, AWS DynamoDB as datasource integration with schema validation (using joi npm package) and entity-relationship and all?

For example, I have to create a microservice which will keep the records of users like their surname, middlename, nameprefix, namesuffix, gender, emails and addresses etc.